# what if I call pthread_detach after pthread_join? A Segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pthreads

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>

void* fun2(void*) {}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "begin" << std::endl;
    std::vector<pthread_t> ths;
    for (int i = 0; i  < 5; ++i)
    {
        pthread_t t;
        pthread_create(&t, 0, fun2, 0);
        ths.push_back(t);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(ths[i], 0);
    }

    pthread_detach(ths[0]);
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I run this code in WSL2, and I got a segmentation fault when it run to **pthread_detach(ths[0])**;
But if I change 5 threads to 4, it will be ok. I don't know why

Comment: not returning something from a function that is declared to return a `void*` is undefined behavior. Your compiler should have warned you

Comment: Why do you `pthread_detach` a thread after you `pthread_join`ed it ?

Comment: why do you not use `std::thread` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number same thing. Even I return nullptr, I still get a segmentation fault when I use more than 4 threads

Comment: @wohlstad I see a video, and the author writes things like this way, but he is fine

Comment: I didnt find anything in the man pages ([here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) and [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html)).  I also wonder why do you want to do this. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: I don't recommend to learn C++ from videos. If they aren't using `std::thread` the video is very likely outdated.

Comment: is it possible that in the original code the loop starts at `1` ? Then it could make sense that only the first thread is detached

Comment: btw fixing the return from `fun2` isnt the "same thing". Undefined behavior in some place can cause strange effects in seemingly unrelated code in other places.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks. So from this point of view, I should avoid writing thread like this -_-||

Comment: I suppose you could do something similar with `std::thread`, but I'd expect it to be simpler to find out whether it is ok to detach an already joined thread.

Comment: `std::thread::detach` will throw if the thread is not joinable https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach.

Comment: thks, I will try it

Comment: Instead of using pthreads, if you use C++11 or later you can also use [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), it returns a std::future object that has some extra synchronization capabilities. It can return values and exceptions from the background thread (which imo is superior to std::thread and join). The destructor of the future will wait for the thread to finish (so you may want to keep it alive as member)

Comment: Oddly enough, [the POSIX specifications for `pthread_detach()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html) say that its behavior when the argument does not designate a joinable thread (as in the example code) is *undefined*.  That's a pretty good reason to avoid doing that, even if Glibc seems to define specific, relatively benign failure behavior for that case.